# How to get array of public fields/properties names?

Tags: typescript, metaprogramming

Say I have a typescript class:

```
class Person
{
    constructor(public readonly firstName: string, public readonly lastName: string, public readonly id: number)
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to list all public properties of the given class using some generic function.

So the hypothetical *getAllPublicProps<...>* would be used like this:

```
const allPublicProps: (keyof Person)[] = getAllPublicProps<Person>() ;
```

and return array of strings equivalent to ['firstName', 'lastName', 'id'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat possible if you can accept a little ugliness, such as instantiating the class and accepting that it will not understand the distinction between private and public properties (unless you encode it somehow).

Suppose you have your class

```
class Person {
  constructor(public readonly firstName: string, 
              public readonly lastName: string,
              public readonly id: number,
              private readonly _secret: number) {}
}
```

You can write a util method

```
class Util {
  static getProperties(obj: any): string[] {
    const result = [];
    for (let property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && !property.startsWith('_')) {
        result.push(property);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

And use it

```
const allProperties = Util.getProperties(new Person());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was hoping it can be done without instantiating the object.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this only works if the property is initialized - which it is automatically if it is declared in the constructor. If it was declared outside the constructor then `hasOwnProperty` won't find it unless it has a "value" - I say that in quotes because `undefined` _does_ count as a value in this case. So this would work: `class Foo{ public name: string = undefined; }` and this works too: `class Foo{ constructor(public name: string){} }` but this does NOT work: `class Foo{ public name: string; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact use case it is hard to give you a concrete answer.
But I am going to try :)

Since TypeScript's type annotations are only available during compile-time and not run-time, there is not really a difference between the properties on compile time anymore. For example:

```
class Person {
    private secret = '123';
    constructor(
        public readonly firstName: string,
        public readonly lastName: string,
        public readonly id: number
    ) { }
}
```

will be compiled to

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName, lastName, id) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
        this.secret = '123';
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

Also, while `type PersonProperties = keyof Person` will give you a string literal type of all public properties, you can not use this type to filter anything, because it is only an annotation. So you can only use `PersonProperties` for function signatures.

Guess you could use [`Reflect`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-reflection-in-depth), but this would include hardcoding the public properties. Also, Angular's compiler is abusing the TS compiler to write metadata that is available during compile time. I don't now if there is any framework agnostic lib that does the same.

Comment: Thank you, I liked your explanation regarding 'no metadata during runtime'; however @Hampus's answer was a bit more accurate :)